# Can't reach the new zend controller/view

Tags: zend-framework, routes

I've installed Zend Studio 7.1.1 that contains 1.9 framework.
For the server side, I use easyphp (very similar to wamp)

When I create the project, I obviously obtain this architecture:

```
MyProject
|-- application
|   |-- Bootstrap.php
|   |-- configs
|   |   `-- application.ini
|   |-- controllers
|   |   |-- ErrorController.php
|   |   `-- IndexController.php
|   |-- models
|   `-- views
|       |-- helpers
|       `-- scripts
|           |-- error
|           |   `-- error.phtml
|           `-- index
|               `-- index.phtml
|-- library
|-- public
|   |-- .htaccess
|   `-- index.php
`-- tests
    |-- application
    |   `-- bootstrap.php
    |-- library
    |   `-- bootstrap.php
    `-- phpunit.xml
```

To launch the project, I enter:

```
http://127.0.0.1/MonProjet/public/index.php
```

But when I create a new controller (TestController.php) and the associated view (application.views/test/index.phtml) and when I enter:

```
http://127.0.0.1/MonProjet/public/test
```

the browser returns the error : object not found (404).

although I activated the mod_rewrite

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

So, how can I set the routing mechanism to reach the new controllers and their views?

Thank you very much,
regards.

Answer (score 1):

It's been quite a while since the question was asked, but nevertheless maybe somebody is still facing the issue. I had the same problem today and it turned out that in apache configuration in httpd.conf the "AllowOverride" was set to "none" and therefore the .htaccess could not be read. Changing it to "All" solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your index.php file has the Autoloader class call which loads all the controller and models automatically.

Along with that you can also add this code in your BootStrap.php file.

```
protected function _initAutoload()
{
    $modeLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array
        ('namespace'=>'Application','basePath'=>APPLICATION_PATH ));

return $modeLoader;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it doesn't work even if I added:
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::registerAutoload();
to load automatically the controllers and the models.
Thanks again.